# Conversion of time zone to specific city

Tags: c#, asp.net, time, sharepoint-2010

I am developing the visual web part in sharepoint using C# .NET.In this application I need to convert the IST timezone to Central time zone of Texas(Dallas). I tried by using 
dateoffsets

and

```
string CSTId = "Central Standard Time";
    TimeZoneInfo CSTZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(CSTId);
    DateTime Date = new DateTime(2014, 1, 05, 11, 50, 0);
    Date = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(Date, CSTZone);
```

But it is not giving me the correct output.

Please suggest an other method.

Comment: Is IST your local timezone?

Comment: Website will be running on the server which is in CST time zone.User input will be IST.I have to convert it into CST an display it.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `ConvertTimeToUtc` which converts to UTC, but you want to convert it to CST.

Try calling [ConvertTime()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb382770%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead, and pass in two TimeZoneInfo objects so you're explicit about what you're converting from and to.